# How to rearrange the official Google Maps' current location button in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps

Google Maps iOS SDK seems to move "My Location" button to bottom-left corner, like

[image]

How to change the frame and button's postion?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't here to write your code for you, it's here to address specific problems after you have shown a clear research effort.

Answer (score 1):

There **isn't** any Public API or method for getting frame or changing my location button in google map.

Solution:

You can hide default google map button, and show your custom button, where you want.

For hiding google current location button:

```
gglMapView.settings.myLocationButton=NO;
```

Add UIButton in place.

Comment: okay thanks but how to implement the google map current location functionality ?

Comment: i am using this only hide the button i asking custom button functionality.